# Don't understand how I am meant to get this answer

Tags: javascript, html

I need to answer a question as follows:

For example, an array of products can be set up as below for use on an ecommerce web site.

```
var products = ["Printer","Tablet","Router"];
```

(i) Set up an array to include the items shown above, plus a few extras of your choice.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p id="How to set up and Array with items in HTML"></p>

        <script>
            var Items = ["Printer", "Tablet", "Router","Headset","Keyboard","Mouse"];
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Items;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: And what is your question here?

Comment: every time I run this code I comes up with exactly what you see above you and I don't know why

Comment: You've only shown HTML with JavaScript you wrote. No results, no explanation what should com up etc. Please edit the question and explain exactly what you're trying to do. You have defined an array, as requested. What then?

Comment: "exactly what you see above", as in the original array in your example? Please don't take it the wrong way, but just make sure you've properly saved your work before refreshing the page.  I've made that mistake before!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the `id` to be `"How to set up and Array with items in HTML"` instead of `"demo"`:

```html
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var Items = ["Printer", "Tablet", "Router","Headset","Keyboard","Mouse"];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Items;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks is I guess its just not me checking the code thanks !

Comment: yea gotta wait 40 seconds